# How does gitlab-ci really work?

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

Which commands are compatible inside a gitlab-ci.yml file. If all shell commands are compatible how does it know when a command fails. i.e if im running a test which outputs which tests fail and succeed, how does the ci interpret this information to detect a failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It recognizes it by the [exit status](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html) of each command:

> Every command returns an exit status (sometimes referred to as a
>   return status or exit code). A successful command returns a 0, while
>   an unsuccessful one returns a non-zero value that usually can be
>   interpreted as an error code. Well-behaved UNIX commands, programs, and
>   utilities return a 0 exit code upon successful completion.

So, if none of the commands returns a non-zero value, the build will pass as successful. You should be able to simulate a failure by calling `exit 1` directly in your job:

```
your_job:
  script:
    - exit 1
```